# how to create macro because values to be copy in DropDown are increasing always. and I have to give Source to Create List in Data Validation

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make drop Down List in sheet2 which contains values from sheet1 column. I have tried this code.

```
Sub testIt() 
 Dim r As Long, endRow As Long, pasteRowIndex As Long

endRow = 10 ' of course it's best to retrieve the last used row number via a function
pasteRowIndex = 1

For r = 1 To endRow 'Loop through sheet1 and search for your criteria

    If Cells(r, Columns("B").Column).Value = "YourCriteria" Then 'Found

            'Copy the current row
            Rows(r).Select
            Selection.Copy

            'Switch to the sheet where you want to paste it & paste
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Rows(pasteRowIndex).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            'Next time you find a match, it will be pasted in a new row
            pasteRowIndex = pasteRowIndex + 1


           'Switch back to your table & continue to search for your criteria
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next r
```

columns in `sheet1` are changing oftenly. so needs to create Dynamic VBA Macro code.

Please guide me for this query.

Comment: This code has nothing to do with creating a dropdown list - do you mean using data validation rules?

Comment: data validation means, It is a option in Excel Data-> Data Validation and then we have to select List and source. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, and the source generates the values to be displayed in the list. You can also achieve this using VBA rather than using the Data menu.

Comment: @SO,  please help me out to solve this using VBA.

Comment: Here you go http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52916&p=270108#post270108

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I don't think that you need a macro to manage the drop down list but perhaps data validation will do. 
Create a new worksheet,
I got a worksheet contain the following data at column A 
[image] 
At the worksheet that i want the dropdownlist, i just highlight the cell and click on the data validation button at data ribbon 
[image]
In the data validation, create the following setting
[image]
Click on the ok button and the list will be created 
[image]

Since in the columns in the worksheet(source) keep on changing, you need write the macro to copy the entire needed column exclude the header of the column to next worksheet(e.g. worksheet that create the dropdown list).

**Edited:** Code to detect the criteria column and copy the column

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim MyWorksheet2 As Worksheet
Dim WantedColumn As Long
Dim ColumnPointer As Long

Sub copyCriteria()

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")
Set MyWorksheet2 = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")

For ColumnPointer = 1 To MyWorksheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 If MyWorksheet.Cells(1, ColumnPointer).Value = "ColumnE" Then
    MyWorksheet.Columns(ColumnPointer).Copy
    MyWorksheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MyWorksheet2.Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp
 End If

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I have to copy all values from column exclude header. Could you help me for this please? because I am not getting any idea for this.

Comment: hi @keong kenshih : what I have to do the next? I have copied that code into next path   Macros->Record Macros-> Macro Name -> Ok-> View Macros->Macro name->Edit.    Now I have pasted your code into this sheet. now what will be the next procedure.please let me know.

Comment: you need assign the macro into a button than it will work. You may refer https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141689 in assigning the macro

Comment: this code doesnt working, It is executing. I have debug it. It doesnt go in to this condtion-                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      If MyWorksheet.Cells(1, ColumnPointer).Value = "ColumnE" Then MyWorksheet.Columns(ColumnPointer).Copy MyWorksheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues Application.CutCopyMode = False MyWorksheet2.Rows("1:1").Delete Shift:=xlUp

Comment: Did you change the code to what you want? I put "ColumnE" because the header called "ColumnE" . You need replace the "ColumnE" with your criteria, don't just simply copy the code and put in the macro to run

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do can be done with a simple named range and Data Validation to use that Name. If you have not heard of Dynamic Ranges, then you should read on.

If **Sheet1** only has the **1** column for the DropDown list via Data Validation, you should use a Named Range instead of a fixed Range. But this named range is dynamic (by using formula)! See [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) usage.

Lets say Sheet1 is like below:
[image: Sheet1]

Lets say the name to be used is **MyList**, then in Excel click **Name Manager** in **Formulas** tab, and place in below as the Range Refers to:
`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))`
[image: NameRange]
[image: NameManager]

Now in Sheet2, the Data Validation is placed on B2, when setting it up, once you put in the source to `=MyList`, Excel highlights it:
[image: DataValidation_1]

Then the drop down list worked:
[image: DropDownList1]

Now if you add data to your list (Column A on Sheet 1), the **MyList** automatically expands and hence your DataValidation drop down list!

Note the list will go up to the first blank cell in Column A, so NO GAPS!

Enjoy!